Getting from Gitlab the exact same archive I get from using "git archive"
I'm in my project's directory and have checked out tag 1.0.  I've pushed this tag to Gitlab and made a release from that tag.  I want to be able to do git archive --format=tgz --prefix myproject-1.0/ HEAD -o myproject-1.0.tar.gz and get a file that matches exactly what I get from downloading a tagged release from Gitlab like this:
wget https://gitlab.com/JoeBlow/myproject/-/archive/1.0/myproject-1.0.tar.gz

Instead I get an archive that is somehow different in the gzip compression.  The underlying tar files are identical.  How can I ensure that I can create an archive on my own machines that's identical to what comes out of Gitlab?

Can you try with different compression levels?

From the docs: "The exact compression settings used to generate a zipball or tarball may change over time. The extracted contents won't change if the branch or tag doesn't change, but the outer compressed archive may have a different byte layout. GitHub will give at least six months' notice before changing compression settings."

See also https://github.blog/open-source/git/update-on-the-future-stability-of-source-code-archives-and-hashes/

Why do you care? If they both decompress to the same thing, there is no concern. In general, different compression software, the same compression software but a different version, or the same software and version with different settings, can all give different compressed output. The only way to assure the same compressed output is to have the exact same software and settings, neither of which you have control or knowledge of.

(@dan1st: to be precise: the OP asked about gitlab, although I agree that all examples of policies chosen by another online service provider may well describe what happens for gitlab too)

like Mark Adler said: I wouldn't expect the gzip implementation on my laptop to be the exact same as the one used in a live online service. The exact gzip implementation may well be updated, be it  on gitlab or on my own laptop (when I update my system). Would you care to explain the need you have behind having byte identical archives ? If this is about publishing releases with a checksum or a signature, I would suggest storing actual, static .tar.gz files on an assets server.

If you want to compare signatures, make them on the .tar files, not the .tar.gz files.

@dan1st I tried different compression settings.
